# can not passing any variable through jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have to set 0 and 1 in mysql table according to checkbox if it is check or not.
I am using jquery ajax function for it,
but jquery function below not passing data to php file.can u please correct my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input.active").click(function() {
// store the values from the form checkbox box, then send via ajax below
var check_active = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
var check_id = $(this).attr('value');
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "dynamicupdateicube.php",
        data: {id: check_id, active: check_active}
        success: function(){
           alert("updated");

        }
    });

});


});
```

It will be good,if u will save my life.

Comment: Syntax Error: Missing `,` after `data: {id: check_id, active: check_active}`

Comment: there is a syntax error, and be sure you have added a jquery library

Comment: @nehaJ Welcome! When developing keep browser console open, use a _smart_ editor that'll detect these errors in first place, use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [jshint](http://jshint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "dynamicupdateicube.php",
        data: {id: check_id, active: check_active},
        success: function(){
           alert("updated");

        }
    });
```

You have missed the comma after the data line and
Put a `,` after `data: {id: check_id, active: check_active}`

Comment: Please don't answer such questions, close as TYPO

Comment: Off-course,it is basic syntax error.

Comment: @rajausmanhaider Yeah got you sir.